# Regex para moneda formato Español Internacional

Tags: java, regex

Estoy tratando de matchear el formato de moneda `xxx.xxx.xxx,xx`, estos son algunos ejemplos de los formatos que serían válidos:

```
29.332.893,32
-29.332.893,32 // Podrían ser numero negativos
29.332.893,322313213123132
00
00,1212
394458,92 // Nótese que los puntos son opcionales
```

Tengo esta Regex: `\b[0-9]+(([\\.][0-9]{3})*([\\,][0-9]+)*)*\b`

El problema está en que en la siguiente lista matchea valores que NO me interesa que matcheen:

```
10.98,09 // Matchea el 10 por un lado y 98,09 por el otro
10.980456 // Matchea el 10
00.2da02 // Matchea el 00
4,098.09 // Matchea 4,098 por un lado y 09 por el otro
121837182372133.321321313 // No debería matchear ya que los puntos es cada 3 numeros, ahora me matchea 121837182372133 por un lado, y 321321313 por el otro
```

Estuve buscando pero no encuentro la manera de que matcheen solo los formatos válidos, ya que estoy usando el Matcher y cuando aparecen los formatos invalidos siempre me quedo con datos que no deberían ser considerados.

**NOTA**

Los importes podrían aparecer de cualquier forma, por ejemplo, el listado de formatos válidos que puse arriba podría aparecer así **(Estos son solo algunos ejemplos)**:

```
total: $         29.332.893,32 // Con el signo y espacios
tosdaasdtal: -29.332.893,32
tosdaasdtal: 29.332.893,32 // Sin el signo pesos
total: 29.332.893,322313213123132 asasasaasdasd
to333tal: $00
toastal: $00,1212
total: $       00
394458,92 // Solo
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿No consideras valores negativos como `-29.230,24`?

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, no lo había tenido en consideración los números negativos. Ahí voy a editar la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tienen 2 formatos válidos:

1. Sin separador de miles:

   ```
   (?:- ?)?\d+(?:,\d+)?
   ```
2. Con puntos como separador de miles:

   ```
   (?:- ?)?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?
   ```

Es decir, juntando ambas expresiones:

```
(?:- ?)?(?:\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)(?:,\d+)?
```

Y, como el número puede estar en cualquier posición del texto, nos aseguraremos de que el mismo no esté rodeado de otro número, ni un punto y un número, ni una coma y un número.

1. ni antecedido por:

   ```
   (?<!\d[.,]?)
   ```
2. ni sucedido por:

   ```
   (?![.,]?\d)
   ```

**Expresión regular**

```
(?:- ?)?(?<!\d[.,]?)(?:\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)(?:,\d+)?(?![.,]?\d)
```

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "(?:- ?)?(?<!\\d[.,]?)(?:\\d{4,}|\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})*)(?:,\\d+)?(?![.,]?\\d)";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

final String texto = "total: $         29.332.893,32"
                   + "\ntosdaasdtal: -29.332.893,32"
                   + "\n10.98,09"
                   + "\n10.980456"
                   + "\n00.2da02"
                   + "\n4,098.09"
                   + "\n121837182372133.321321313"
                   + "\ntosdaasdtal: 29.332.893,32"
                   + "\ntotal: 29.332.893,322313213123132 asasasaasdasd";
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

System.out.println("Texto: \n" + texto + "\n");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Número encontrado: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Número encontrado: 29.332.893,32
Número encontrado: -29.332.893,32
Número encontrado: 02
Número encontrado: 29.332.893,32
Número encontrado: 29.332.893,322313213123132
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/91hay3

Comment: Nuevamente excelente Mariano. Funcionó perfectamente, gracias!

Comment: Para el caso de `00.2da02` matchea con `02`... Puedo agregar que no esté precedido por una letra.. ¿Qué te parece que debería hacer?

Comment: Así está perfecto, ya que las cadenas son casi aleatorias quizás me quedo sin valores por el hecho de que están predecedidos por una letra. En cuyo caso solo habría que cambiar `(?![.,]?\d)` por `(?![.,]?\d|[^0-9])`, no?

Comment: Para verificar que no esté precedido por una letra, se debería cambiar `(?<!\d[.,]?)` por `(?<!\d[.,]?|[A-Za-z])` ... Pare que no esté sucedido, cambiar `(?![.,]?\\d)` por `(?![.,]?\\d|[A-Za-z])`.